# expansion of tikz coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I trid to draw a line with `TikZ` and failed, as the code of `version 1` shows. I think this is because the expression `\pgfmathresult\textwidth` for the end coodinate does not expand. So I tried the code of `version 2` and `version 3`, attempting to expand `\pgfmathresult\textwidth` first. But both does not work either. Why?

Though the code of `version 4` typesets the line as expected, I don't want to introduce an auxilary macro(here is `\x`).

So, how to expand an expression in coodinates in the scope of `TikZ` itself?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz}
\geometry{showframe}


\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{0.1+0.2}\pgfmathresult

% Version 0:
V0: |\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\textwidth * \value{page} / 3,0);|

% Version 1: fail
V1: |\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\pgfmathresult\textwidth,0);|

% version 2: fail
V2: |\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\expanded{\pgfmathresult\textwidth},0);|

% version 3: fail
V3: |\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\the\dimexpr\textwidth * \pgfmathresult\relax,0);|

% version 4: works, but I don't want to introduce an new auxilary macro.
V4: |\edef\x{\noexpand\tikz\noexpand\draw(0,0)--(\pgfmathresult\textwidth,0);}\x|

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfmathresult` is not guaranteed to persist beyond the immediate calculation.  Does it work if you save the result in a different macro immediately after calculating it?

Comment: @AndrewStacey I was just about to write an answer with this :) That's indeed the issue and fix for it.

Comment: Use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mytmp}{0.1+0.2}` and `\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\mytmp*\textwidth,0);`. “I don't want” is not good enough in front of reality (what Andrew mentioned).

Comment: Since `\pgfmathresult` is used to store the result of calculation, why does another temp macro have to be used to store again the result? And why are my codes of `version2` and `version 3` not correct ways to expand the expression?

Comment: Similar to pgf issue #787: [Drawing code clobbers \pgfmathresult](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/787). Can't say it's not fixable, but I'm afraid the behavior won't change in recent future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

I suggest two easier approaches:

- **V5:** Use a variable to save the result and use it later (`\let\mylinefactor\pgfmathresult`). This also allows you to calculate multiple things with `\pgfmathparse` afterwards.
- **V6:** If you need the variable only once, you could put the calculation inside the tikz expression if you add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz}
\geometry{showframe}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{0.1+0.2}\pgfmathresult
\let\mylinefactor\pgfmathresult % save the result

\pgfmathparse{0.2+0.3}\pgfmathresult % so you could make other calculations afterwards

% Version 0:
V0: |\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\textwidth * \value{page} / 3,0);|

% Version 5: works
V5: |\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\mylinefactor\textwidth,0);|

% Version 6: works
V6: |\tikz\draw(0,0)--({(0.1+0.2)*\textwidth},0);|

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lines without `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xfp}
\parindent0pt
\def\factor{\fpeval{0.1+0.2}}
\begin{document}
V7: |\rule{\dimexpr \textwidth * \value{page} / 3}{0.5pt}|

V8: |\rule{\dimexpr \factor\textwidth}{0.5pt}|
\end{document}
```

[image]